# mongoose.populate() with graphql is not able to perform 'infinite' queries

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, graphql, graphql-js

I have a stack of ApolloServer for GraphQL with MongoDB as a database with mongoose as a library.
I have now set up my code that I am able to perform some queries that goes 2-3 levels in to deep. But when I try to query further and go to my original object. It will return me with a null.

I have tried the solution of Academind already with some youtube films + searching the world of internet, however. No solutions found to this yet.

My resolver functions

```
module.exports = {
  Query: {
    athlete: async (root, args, context) => {
      return await Athlete.findOne({ _id: args._id }).populate('results');
    },
    race: async (root, args) => {
      return await Race.findOne({ _id: args._id }).populate('athletes');
    },
    result: async (root, args) => {
      return await Result.findOne({ _id: args._id })
        .populate('race')
        .populate('athlete')
        .exec();
    },
    athletes: async () => {
      return await Athlete.find().populate('results');
    },

    races: async () => {
      return await Race.find().populate('athletes');
    },

    results: async () => {
      return await Result.find()
        .populate('race')
        .populate('athlete')
        .exec();
    }  
  }
};
```

Easier is to go to github though: https://github.com/axelvuylsteke/fullstack-graphql-vue/tree/graphQL_stackOverflow_question

```
npm run dev to start it in dev mode.
```

You can run the queries, first one you will get a null for the race.name, second one when you take results as a source root, you get a value for the name:

```
query searchAthlete {
  athlete(_id: "5d690a25a1917025486c27ac") {
    _id
    country
    results{
      _id
      race{
        _id
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
query searchResults {
  results {
    _id
    race{
      _id
      name
    }
  }
}
```

I expect to have infinite possibilities to go through the queries from object to object...
You can normally connect to the mongoDB as the dev mode is set to all open IP adresses.
Little background:
An athlete will store a race result.
A race will store all participated athletes.
A result will store the result itself with an athlete and the race where the result is performed.